# Como puedo almacenar todos los resultados del bucle y sumarlos al final

Tags: javascript

Tengo este bucle:

```
let a=0;
let b=1;
let f=0;



for (let n=0; n<50; n++) {

  switch(n) {
    case 0: f=0; break;
    case 1: f=1; break;
    default: {
      f=a+b; 
      a=b;
      b=f;

    }   
  }

  console.log("n="+n+" f="+f);      
}
```

Necesito almacenar todos los resultados de f y sumarlos al final mostrandolos por consola.

He probado con resultado += f; pero me da un valor no deseado.

Comment: ¿Puedes aclararnos que es cada variable? ¿Que es a, b y f? ¿Porque el for es hasta 50? ¿Que te refieres con todos los resultados?

Comment: me da esto: `n=49 f=7778742049` al final, ese resultado no quieres?

Comment: Hola, es la serie de fibonaci hasta el 50, lo que queria era sumar todos los resultados que da f, al final he usado let suma = 0; ..... suma += f y la he puesto en el cosole.log. Gracias por la ayuda!